# "Employee in accounting" and "employee in accounts"

Tags: vocabulary

What's the difference between *employee in accounting* and *employee in accounts*? 
Are these correct names for an occupation?

Answer (score 2):

> What's the difference between "employee in accounting" and "employee in accounts".

In those phrases, I would interpret both *accounting* and *accounts* to refer to the department within an organisation which handles the accounts, which is to say does the accounting.

> Are these correct names for an occupation?

No, because I don't know what that employee does in accounts or in accounting.

Now, *accounting* is indeed a job, and is something that *accountants* do, along with some related occupations like *accounts technicians*.

Someone working "in accounts" could be doing a job in that department that requires no knowledge on their part of actual accounting, but supports those who do. Maybe they're an office admin or IT specialist who just happen to work in a department that deals with accounting.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, I would only expect to hear "employee in accounting" since accounting is the noun used to describe that profession. However, "employee in accounts" may be plausibly used as part of office-lingo in a company that had a department which focused on 'accounts payable' or on 'customer accounts' or something of that sort.

Answer (score 0):

Accounting relates to payments made to and from the company. Accounts relates to relations with clients.

Answer (score 0):

oh, thanks a lot! And would "working in accounts"/"... in accounting" a write answer to the question "Current activity/occupation", if I simply did different things in the accounting department ( so, not only booking invoices, creating warnings etc., but also other thing, which have hardly anything to do whith the actual accounting )? Or should it be "accountant" or "bookkeeper" as well, even though the question isn't "occupation", but "activity/occupation"?